# Unable to login with received access token from oauth header

Tags: facebook-oauth

Using the following header as specified in the facebook developers site, an access token is received

Step 1: 
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...
&scope=publish_stream
&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/example/`

Step2:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? client_id=.....&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/example/&client_secret=....
&scope=publish_stream
&code=AQALNcjIpXfqYiegdhqlpJYRa1XXwIhPdxnyehE-bf3PjNUYk2dKQlVDG3vy4xgmR4gwbe7t7qoOwfR2gpAk4vY4PeBga6w2BvM_rTDHzUfQ73koPMMlrXdGqeSPyNds9Wy3ccWufrMzjQpmo52xYPD4QZuvNnvObIY3ICxu5XxOG4HgV-OFR_JLsTD8ThXoFH5LpJlM76ynthcOz2TovbTq#*=*

After step 2 an access token is received .

Can this access token be used in oauth signature header? when used inoauth signature header its returning " use a valid access token"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is not expecting oauth signature header.